# Is there any way to validate the enities in EF Core to make sure all non-null values are set

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core

I have a parent entity `Signup` and child entities `OutdoorSignup` and `IndoorSignup`. An event can be outdoor or indoor and has a list of signups (`List<Signup>`).

The issue is that when I save say an `OutdoorSignup` to an `Event`, it only validates the parent `Signup`. It does not check if the child `Signup`'s non-null values are not null. Is there any way to validate the `OutdoorSignup` entity before I add it to the `Event`?

I tried looking online and could not find much about this. Any help is appreciated!